# How do you accept 1 or 2 string variable with console.next() in shortest code, Java?

Tags: java

For example I want to accept Hammer or Nail Gun with the space. I am sending this information as a string to a method, so I can not have a space after. I need to send either "Hammer" or "Nail Gun" and other similar items with one or two words only.

```
String name = console.next() + " " + console.next();
```

fails to work as if someone enters Hammer, it waits for the next entry.

Btw, I can use console.nextLine, but was hoping to add some security as to full line of code.

Comment: Using nextLine() is really the best thing to do, IMO

Comment: *"in shortest code"*  That is just silly.  Code should be readable for people, logical and well designed.  'Shortest' is the bottom of the list.  *"add some security"* Security?  What security is either required or provided by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `console` is an instance of `Scanner`, there are many ways to solve this problem.

The simplest is to use [`console.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead of `.next()`.  That way, the user can enter multiple words and complete their input by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Alternatively, you could use [`console.nextLine(Pattern pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) and provide a pattern which is a regular expression that matches your desired input.

Answer (score 1):

What you should use is `console.nextLine()`.

Then you can inspect that input and determine if it is what you expect.

I would grab the entire line of text.  Than you could use `indexOf(" ")` to see if there is a space in the text.  Doing it the other way (with `console.next()`) is much more complicated.